# Mapping export data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have export functionality using [laravel excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1). currently my data is exporting but i want to add related table data into my csv instead of just id.

## sample

This is what I get currently

> id-name-**core_id**-created_at-updated_at

What I want to get

> id-name-**core_name**-created_at-updated_at

For this matter I've found mapping ([source](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html)) might be the solution, but it export blank csv.

## Code

`Export class`

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\CableAlokasi;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

// added
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;

class CableAlokasiExport implements WithMapping
{
    use Exportable;

    private $fileName = 'Alokasies.csv';

    /**
    * Optional Writer Type
    */
    private $writerType = Excel::CSV;

    /**
    * Optional headers
    */
    private $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    ];


    // added for mapping data
    public function map($alokasi): array
    {
        return [
            $alokasi->id,
            $alokasi->core->name,
            $alokasi->name,
            $alokasi->created_at,
            $alokasi->updated_at,
        ];
    }
    //

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            '#',
            'core',
            'name',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ];
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return CableAlokasi::all();
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
public function export(Request $request) 
{
    $filename = Carbon::now()->format('Ymdhms').'-Alokasies.xlsx';
    Excel::store(new CableAlokasiExport, $filename);
    $fullPath = url('exports', $filename);

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $fullPath,
        'message' => 'Alokasies are successfully exported.'
    ], 200);
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: did u check error log?

Comment: @ShafeequeTP i don't get error my export file starts to download with no issue, just is empty

Comment: may have some warnings that can help you to identify the problem

Comment: @ShafeequeTP `message: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"`

Comment: @ShafeequeTP I also found [this](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1658#issuecomment-388367964) and changed my collection function result is same error

Comment: @ShafeequeTP foud the issue :) some of my data didn't have `core_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Some of my data `core_id` columns were null that's why it couldn't export data properly.